# createTableIfNotExists error - relation already exist

Tags: java, sqlite, postgresql, ormlite

In my backend:

```
//create ConnectioSource
private static final String DB_NAME = "development";
private ConnectionSource connectionSource;
private String databaseUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" + DB_NAME;

public ConnectionSource getConnectionSource() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(databaseUrl, "user", "333444");
        return connectionSource;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But when I try restart backend, I receive error

> "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "buyer_users" already exist"

```
ConnectionSource connectionSource = dbHelper.getConnectionSource();
TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, BuyerUser.class);
```

When I use `SQLite` db, method `createTableIfNotExists` work fine, but what happend when I use `postgres`?

**UPDATE:**

My solution:

```
 List<String> tablesList = new ArrayList<String>();
 DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
 ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);

 while (rs.next()) {
     tablesList.add(rs.getString(3));
 }

 if(!tablesList.contains("buyer_users"))
     TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, BuyerUser.class);
```

Comment: Which version of  ormlite are you using

Comment: I use 4.43 ormlite version.

Comment: This bug was fixed for SqlLite http://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/bugs/82/ but i guess not for postgres

Comment: 4.48 version - nothing has changed. The only way out - custom method `createTableIfNotExist`...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem today with OrmLite 4.48 and PostgreSQL 9.1.

What I ended doing is the following:

```
// create the table if it does not exist
if(!dao.isTableExists()) {
    // use dao.isTableExists() first, as createTableIfNotExists() fails with postgreSQL 9.1 (OrmLite 4.48)
    TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(_pooledConnectionSrc, entityClass);
}
```

Obviously this code assumes that you have any interest in creating the corresponding DAO instance. I do, in my project. To create the DAO corresponding to your table, see "createDao" method from the class DaoManager.

(Code tested on both PgSQL 9.1 and MySQL 5.5)

Comment: Thanks. This really helped. I was encountering the same error.